# How to get the owner process of a socket?

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel

Given a socket struct, is there any way that I can get the owner process of this socket in a kernel module? That is, given a socket structure, I am trying to get the process descriptor (task_struct struct) of its owner process?

My original idea is to traverse the tasklist. For each process p traversed, just check whether p's open file descriptors contains one that is the same as the file descriptor associated with the socket struct. (In struct socket, there is a field struct file *file).

I am not sure whether the kernel allows me to traverse the tasklist or not. Anyone has some idea of how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a so bad idea. Look at this code I have written someday:

```c
struct task_struct *task;
struct list_head *t, *t1;
...
list_for_each(t, t1) {
#ifdef CONFIG_UIDGID_STRICT_TYPE_CHECKS
    if ((task_uid(task)).val == 0) /* no root processes, only userspace*/
#else
    if ((task_uid(task)) == 0)
#endif
    continue;
    task = list_entry(t, struct task_struct, tasks);
    /*Now you have task_struct of userspace program*/
    /*and may do whatever you want ))) */
    /*E.g. to figure out opened file descriptors*/
}
```

A little addition: I think you know that this code should be run in single kernel thread. There's no neen to execute it init function of kernel module.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. BTW, what kernel version is your module code running against?

Comment: Against? May be you mean ... running on?
I've tested on kernel version 3.2.0, 3.10.2